# How do you delete an attribute in XML?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, e4x

How do I delete an attribute on an XML node in E4X? I thought this would be easier but I haven't found any examples.

I tried:

```
delete xml.attribute("myAttribute");
```

which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1119: Delete operator is not supported with operand of type XMLList.
```

and I've tried:

```
xml.attribute("myAttribute") = null;
```

which causes a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you example just add the `[0]` in the resulted XMLList, to ensure you delete a single attribute node, it should work:

```
delete xml.@attributename[0];
```

Actually, for me `delete` with `XMLList` works as well for simple cases (without complex e4x search constructions):

```
    var x:XML = <x><c a="1"/><c a="2"/></x>;
    trace("0", x.toXMLString());
    delete x.c.@a;
    trace("1", x.toXMLString());
```

output:

```
[trace] 0 <x>
[trace]   <c a="1"/>
[trace]   <c a="2"/>
[trace] </x>
[trace] 1 <x>
[trace]   <c/>
[trace]   <c/>
[trace] </x>
```

Comment: My attribute is on the root node. If you put `a` on `x` do you get the error that I mention in the OP?

Comment: for root attributes this works the same for me as in my example, that is all fine (I checked on SDK 3.6A and SDK 4.6). Which SDK do you use?

Comment: I'm using 4.6 as well. It works now. I compared with an earlier version and I had tried `delete xml.attribute("myAttribute");` but didn't try `delete xml.@myAttribute;` like in your answer which works. Thanks